# How to generate new wallets in anchor typescript tests

Tags: anchor, pda, testing, anchor-test, typescript

I'm writing some unit tests and want to test that a user cannot update data on a PDA created by another user.  How can I get "another user?"  I'm creating the first user:

```
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env()
anchor.setProvider(provider)
```

Then

```
await program.methods
        .createPda('data')
        .accounts({
          user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        })
        .rpc()
```

Then I want to call updatePda with another wallet like so:

```
await program.methods
        .updatePda('NEW DATA')
        .accounts({
          user: another_provider.another_wallet.publicKey,
        })
        .rpc()
```

Is this doable in anchor?  Do I need a new wallet on the same provider, or do I need an entirely new provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another user in your case is any `Keypair`

You can generate another `Keypair` using:

```
const user1 = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const user2 = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
```

Then you can call `updatePda` with `user1.publicKey`